# Linear Layout background image not visible on few devices

Tags: android, image, background

I am using linear layout to set background image for the screen, It visible on emulator, samsung J7 and samsung duos but not visible on galaxy S5. why this difference happend ? how to add to image as background resources for Linear Layout.This is my xml file I have done.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg">

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you post the screenshot of the activity?

Comment: showing white empty(white) screen

Comment: Check the answer below and reply me if that works.

Comment: try putting different size images in hdpi,xhdpi, mdpi folder . use android studio asset manager

Comment: ok, I will try this

Answer (score 0):

Well in order to resolve this :

You may check the execution of the code by providing a color to the background as because the image may have resolution issues and might not be displayed.

So, in order to resolve this resolution issue you are supposed to provide different size of images in hdpi, xhdpi, mdpi folder.